# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, keras-2

I am doing some task related to image captioning and I have loaded the weights of inception model like this

```
model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet')
```

But I am getting error like this:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'
```

What should I do? Please help.
Here is the full output of above code.

1 . --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent
    call last)  in ()
          1 # Load the inception v3 model
    ----> 2 model = InceptionV3(include_top=True,weights='imagenet')
          3 #         InceptionV3(weights='imagenet')

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/applications/__init__.py
in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     26             kwargs['models'] = models
     27             kwargs['utils'] = utils
---> 28         return base_fun(*args, **kwargs)
     29 
     30     return wrapper

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/applications/inception_v3.py
in InceptionV3(*args, **kwargs)
      9 @keras_modules_injection
     10 def InceptionV3(*args, **kwargs):
---> 11     return inception_v3.InceptionV3(*args, **kwargs)
     12 
     13 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_applications/inception_v3.py
in InceptionV3(include_top, weights, input_tensor, input_shape,
pooling, classes, **kwargs)
    155 
    156     if input_tensor is None:
--> 157         img_input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    158     else:
    159         if not backend.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/input_layer.py
in Input(shape, batch_shape, name, dtype, sparse, tensor)
    176                              name=name, dtype=dtype,
    177                              sparse=sparse,
--> 178                              input_tensor=tensor)
    179     # Return tensor including _keras_shape and _keras_history.
    180     # Note that in this case train_output and test_output are the same pointer.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py
in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/input_layer.py
in __init__(self, input_shape, batch_size, batch_input_shape, dtype,
input_tensor, sparse, name)
     37         if not name:
     38             prefix = 'input'
---> 39             name = prefix + '_' + str(K.get_uid(prefix))
     40         super(InputLayer, self).__init__(dtype=dtype, name=name)
     41 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py
in get_uid(prefix)
     72     """
     73     global _GRAPH_UID_DICTS
---> 74     graph = tf.get_default_graph()
     75     if graph not in _GRAPH_UID_DICTS:
     76         _GRAPH_UID_DICTS[graph] = defaultdict(int)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute
'get_default_graph'
```

Comment: Do you have a file called tensorflow.py in your codebase? How did you install tensorflow?

Comment: Are you using tensorflow 2.0? Are you in eager mode?

Comment: @Vlad  thanks for the reply but i resolved this issue after updating keras,tensorflow,and conda 's all packages .

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro thanks for your reply but i resolved this issue after updating keras,tensorflow,and conda 's all packages and i don't have file called tensorflow.py

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change

```
Import keras.<something>.<something>
```

to

```
Import tensorflow.keras.<something>.<something>
```

where "something" refers to the module you want to import. It worked for me.

Comment: i don't know above answer work or not but i updated my Environment and it worked i think there was an issue related to compatibility.

Comment: Worked for me, using tensorflow 2

Answer (score 3):

Another cause due to which this is happening is that in **tensorflow_backend.py**

located  in : *lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/*

uses **tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph** for obtaining graph

instead of **tf.get_default_graph**.

By replacing this in the directory this problem can be solved successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Keras integrated into TensorFlow 2.0

The article below cleared this up for me.  Key points are:

1. Keras is included in the TensorFlow 2.0 package
2. So no need to install the stand-alone Keras package in your environment
3. And now the fore-mentioned solutions of using "from tensorflow.keras…" make sense.

After recognizing that and making the change, my code samples work with some minor changes here and there.
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/21/keras-vs-tf-keras-whats-the-difference-in-tensorflow-2-0/

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by replacing **tensorflow.keras**.* to **tensorflow.python.keras**.*

Working example:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
```

Answer (score 1):

Two Steps solved this issue for me in Google Colabs

**First Step**

Change

from  keras.something import something

To

from tensorflow.keras.something import something

**Second Step**

Use

tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph

instead of tf.get_default_graph

Reason

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/21/keras-vs-tf-keras-whats-the-difference-in-tensorflow-2-0/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, replacing

**from keras.models import models**

with:

**from tensorflow.keras.models import models**

in my script, fixed this problem.